# LEFT JOIN returns 1st row from left table only if right table is empty

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I have two tables with following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then I add 3 rows to the **countries** table:

```
INSERT INTO `countries` VALUES
  (DEFAULT, 'India'),
  (DEFAULT, 'Pakistan'),
  (DEFAULT, 'Afghanistan');
```

Now, when I run the following query:

```
SELECT c.title, COUNT(c2.id) AS cities
FROM countries AS c
  LEFT JOIN cities AS c2
    ON c2.country_id = c.id
GROUP BY c2.country_id;
```

I get:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
| title       | cities |
++++++++++++++++++++++++
| India       | 0      |
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I expect is:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
| title       | cities |
++++++++++++++++++++++++
| India       | 0      |
| Pakistan    | 0      |
| Afghanistan | 0      |
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I do not know why the query is returning only 1 row from the left table. Can anybody please help?

Comment: You need to use  `Group by c.id`. I am open to give an explanation if required.

Comment: @1000111 It works :) Can you please post this as an explanatory answer so I could accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want result for all the entries of `countries` table irrespective of whether the corresponding records in `cities` table exist or not then `LEFT JOIN` is the right choice.

For some countries corresponding entries in `cities` table might not exist. In this case you will get `NULL` for those.

Since no entries exist in `cities` table you will get `NULL` for `c2.country_id` for all the rows of `countries` table.

Here `NULL` represents your group.

If there were anything other than null then you would get more than 1 row.
But in your case you are grouping by `NULL`.

Look, `c.id` isn't null in those cases and if you would group by `c.id` then there would be three distinct ids in your sample input. So, you would get three rows in your result set.

```
SELECT c.title, COUNT(c2.id) AS cities
FROM countries AS c
  LEFT JOIN cities AS c2
    ON c2.country_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

---

**More:**

**Some subtleties regarding `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT COUNT(0);   Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(-1);  Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(NULL); Result: 0

SELECT COUNT(71); Result: 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0)